# Twilio verification code immediately expired and leads to 'too many attempts' errors - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to sign up for an account with twilio. However, the verification code doesn't seem to work with the system claiming it is expired, even though it just arrived. Eventually the system will claim too many attempts. What am I doing wrong?

Create an account and when it asks for a phone number to verify it's your phone, enter your details.
[image: Enter phone number]

Wait for the verification code to arrive and enter it. The code is already expired, even though just 5 seconds old.
[image: Verification code expired]

Tried it a few times, also with resend code. Eventually, the system claims too many attempts.
[image: Too many attempts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from your screenshot that you're trying to sign up with a German number. It seems, we currently have some issues with the 2FA verification for some numbers.

But luckily, there is a workaround. Try to enter your phone number with a leading 0 after the country code:

> +49 0 151 1234124

This should hopefully do the trick until we fix this issue.

I can't wait to see what you'll build with Twilio!